# Xcode quit unexpectedly in interface builder

Tags: crash, xcode6, interface-builder

I started a new project in Xcode (Cocoa App OSX, Objective-C). Every time I try to add a button to a window in Interface Builder(drag and drop) I receive the following error and Xcode quits.
"UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSUnknownKeyException): [ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key springLoaded."

Xcode Version 6.3 (6D570) on Yosemite 10.10.3

Anyone experienced such behavior?

part of the crash:

```
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6D570
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSUnknownKeyException): [<NSButton 0x7fb46e18f090> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key springLoaded.
UserInfo: {
    NSTargetObjectUserInfoKey = "<NSButton: 0x7fb46e18f090>";
    NSUnknownUserInfoKey = springLoaded;
}
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00007fff90a4c4f4 __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x00000001050ee184 DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x00007fff90d1976e objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  3  0x00007fff90a4c0a9 -[NSException raise] (in CoreFoundation)
  4  0x00007fff8dc77d25 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForUndefinedKey:] (in Foundation)
  5  0x00007fff8db4cccb -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] (in Foundation)
```

Update:
Xcode now somehow survived the button add but when I try to save I get this Alert:
Unfortunately this happens with Xcode 6.3.1

[image: alert]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got an answer from apple devforums.

The reason for this is that I use OSX seed build OS X 10.10.3 (14D87h).

> This is new API related to Force Touch trackpads. It was added in OS X
>   10.10.3, but only in seed builds