# Unrecognized Selector "isSpringLoaded" Sent to NSButton in Xib in XCode 6.3

Tags: xcode6, interface-builder, xib

Whenever I save my xib file after adding a button on it, the following error occurs: `-[NSButton isSpringLoaded]` unrecognized selector sent to instance.

XCode version is 6.3. How to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Xcode quit unexpectedly in interface builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29747736/xcode-quit-unexpectedly-in-interface-builder)

Upgrade to the latest OS X (currently 10.10.3 as of posting)

Apparently, Xcode IB engineers don't believe in using respondsToSelector: in their versioned API